# C# Getting a JSON object

Tags: c#, json, multithreading, parsing, object

So I have a City class that I want to be able to get and store JSON data.

```
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
    public string region { get; set; }
    public string mainCity { get; set; }
    public string latitude { get; set; }
    public string longitude { get; set; }
    public string comment { get; set; }
    public bool wasThereAnError { get; set; }

    public class CityResponse
    {
        public string status { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public List<City> result { get; set; }
    }
```

In my App I need to request a City by an ID or display a list of Cities by a country code so I want the City to be a base class.

Here is the code I am trying to use to make this happe. It is in a WebRetrieval class

```
    async private Task<City> GetCityInformation(string url)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var response = await client.GetAsync(new Uri(url));

        string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        //var cityRootaaa = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<City.CityResponse>(result);
        var cityRoot = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<City>(result);
        return cityRoot;
}

    //Return City
    async public Task<City> GetCity(string url)
    {
        City city = await GetCityInformation(url);
        return city;
    }
```

And then when I try to make a City object in the City_Page class, I use this:

```
            long cityNum = Convert.ToInt64(CityID_Textbox.Text);
            string url = "http://honey.computing.dcu.ie/city/city.php?id=" + cityNum;


            City city = wr.GetCity(url);
            myTextBlock1.Text = city.ToString();
```

I keep getting erros about System.Threading.tasks.task not being able to be converted to CityApp.City.

I'm really stumped and I don't know what to do. Right now the code is broken and I have no idea how to fix it. So I would really appreciate any help with it.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to the other answers, you should delete your `SerializeObject` statement and simply deserialize the string into a `City` object.

```
    //result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response);

    var city = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<City>(result);
```

Comment: I tried this and it worked but there is an error. It doesn't store any of the values. id and all are null

Comment: Step through the code with the debugger and show us the value of `result`

Comment: Result is filled correclty "{\"status\":\"okay\",\"result\":{\"id\":1,\"country\":\"US\",\"region\":\"NY\",\"city\":\"Valhalla\",\"latitude\":41.0877,\"longitude\":-73.7768,\"comment\":\"974343 monkeys\"}}"


So i'm not sure what is going wrong

Comment: I am not sure if Json.Net's deserialization is case-insensitive by default... but try adding, for example, `[JsonProperty("status")` (notice the small 's') to your `Status` property, and see if you can deserialize that specific property.

Comment: When I try to do it, it fails because it says something about needing an array

Comment: Are you trying to deserialize into a `City` or `CityResponse`? How are you using that class? Simply deserializing into a `City` *should* work. You're doing something wrong.

Comment: Into a City. I updated the code in the OP if you want to take a look.
When I debug into the object, I can see that status has been set to okay, however the rest of the information is set to null so it's like it is only picking up my CityResponse thing which is weird

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41133/discussion-between-andyohart-and-dcastro)

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
City city = wr.GetCity(url);
```

to

```
City city = wr.GetCity(url).Result;
```

if you're using .Net 4.0; if you're using 4.5, then

```
City city = await wr.GetCity(url);
```

Also, you're returning a CityResponse not just a City; the Json is failing to deserialize because it lacks [] to define the array. If you do the following

```
        var cityResponse = new CityResponse();
        cityResponse.status = "okay";
        cityResponse.result = new List<City>();
        var city = new City();
        city.Status = "0";
        city.Id = "1";
        city.Country = "2";
        city.Region = "3";
        city.MainCity = "4";
        city.Latitude = "5";
        city.Longitude = "6";
        city.Comment = "7";
        city.WasThereAnError = false;

        cityResponse.result.Add(city);

        var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cityResponse);
```

jsonString will be

"{\"status\":\"okay\",\"Message\":null,\"result\":[{\"Status\":\"0\",\"Id\":\"1\",\"Country\":\"2\",\"Region\":\"3\",\"MainCity\":\"4\",\"Latitude\":\"5\",\"Longitude\":\"6\",\"Comment\":\"7\",\"WasThereAnError\":false}]}"

Comment: Yeah it worked using await however the City object isn't storing anything in it for some reason. I used breakpoints and I cannot see anything in it. Id and everything is null

Comment: Are you sure you're getting back City and not CityResponse?

Comment: @dcastro I just checked and result is storing the json correclty. I replied to you below

Comment: @AllanElder I am getting back the City so it only has Status in it. But for some reason I can't get the CityResponse to return it gives me errors about not being an array or something

Comment: @AndyOHart I updated the answer, hopefully it gets you on the right track; your service is returning a CityResponse http://honey.computing.dcu.ie/city/city.php?id=1

Answer (score 1):

Your `GetCity` method is `async`, so you have to `await` it to get a `City` instead of a `Task<City>`.

```
City city = await wr.GetCity(url);
```

Comment: Doing that fixes the error, however my City object is empty when I query the website. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

GetCity already awaits and should retung City instead of Task.

Comment: I can't make it just return City since it's async

Comment: public City GetCity(string url)
    {
      var city = GetCityInformation(url).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
      return city;
    }